# Querying complete JSON object using elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I want to query for the complete Json.

I have Json objects saved in in different documents.

```
_id: 1,
my_json: {
              "field1": "1",
              "field2": "2",
              "field3": "3",
              "field4": "4"
          }
_id: 2,
my_json: {
              "field1": "11",
              "field2": "22",
              "field3": "33",
              "field4": "44"
          }
```

In my query I want to match for the complete combination not the single field. So I tried the query below but it is returning empty response.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "my_json": [
              {
                "field1": "11",
                "field2": "22",
                "field3": "33",
                "field4": "44"
              },
              {
                "field1": "1",
                "field2": "2",
                "field3": "3",
                "field4": "4"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I need to work with more and more Json objects like above. So I cannot use the regular query.Hence I tried to match the complte the JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match all properties of a JSON object, you can do so but using one term query per field in your JSON, i.e. each field of your JSON **must** match

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "my_json.field1": "11"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "my_json.field2": "22"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "my_json.field3": "33"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "my_json.field4": "44"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to match the complete combination(json object) across different documents.

Comment: Yes, I only use a single doc, but you can add as many must constraints as you wish